# Errors while installing R packages

Tags: r, solaris, rcpp

While installing R packages into solaris server, we got the below error:

"/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include" is present in our server, where as while installing the package, some script is executing internally and looking for `"I/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include"`, its not found.

```
I"/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/include  -KPIC   -c api.cpp -o api.o
sh: I/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include: not found

make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `Rcpp.so'
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rcpp'
```

Full `install.packages()` output:

```
 installing *source* package 'Rcpp' ...
** package 'Rcpp' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
I"/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/include  -KPIC   -c api.cpp -o api.o
sh: I/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include: not found
*** Error code 127 (ignored)
I"/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/include  -KPIC   -c attributes.cpp -o attributes.o
sh: I/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include: not found
*** Error code 127 (ignored)
I"/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/include  -KPIC   -c barrier.cpp -o barrier.o
sh: I/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include: not found
*** Error code 127 (ignored)
I"/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/include  -KPIC   -c date.cpp -o date.o
sh: I/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include: not found
*** Error code 127 (ignored)
I"/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/include  -KPIC   -c module.cpp -o module.o
sh: I/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include: not found
*** Error code 127 (ignored)
I"/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/include  -KPIC   -c rcpp_init.cpp -o rcpp_init.o
sh: I/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include: not found

*** Error code 127 (ignored)
-shared -L/usr/local/lib -o Rcpp.so api.o attributes.o barrier.o date.o module.o rcpp_init.o
sh: line 2: -shared: not found
*** Error code 127
The following command caused the error:
if test  "zapi.o attributes.o barrier.o date.o module.o rcpp_init.o" != "z"; then \
  echo  -shared  -L/usr/local/lib -o Rcpp.so api.o attributes.o barrier.o date.o module.o rcpp_init.o   ; \
   -shared  -L/usr/local/lib -o Rcpp.so api.o attributes.o barrier.o date.o module.o rcpp_init.o   ; \
fi
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `Rcpp.so'
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rcpp'
* removing '/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/library/Rcpp'
```

makeconf entries as follows: (we have altered the CXX, CXX11, CXX14)

```
enter code here
# etc/Makeconf.  Generated from Makeconf.in by configure.
#
# ${R_HOME}/etc/Makeconf
#
# R was configured using the following call
# (not including env. vars and site configuration)
# configure 

## This fails if it contains spaces, or if it is quoted
include $(R_SHARE_DIR)/make/vars.mk

AR = ar
BLAS_LIBS = -L"$(R_HOME)/lib$(R_ARCH)" -lRblas
C_VISIBILITY = -fvisibility=hidden
CC = gcc -std=gnu99
CFLAGS = -g -O2 $(LTO)
CPICFLAGS = -fPIC
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include
CXX = /opt/csw/gcc4/bin
CXXCPP = /lib/cpp
CXXFLAGS =  $(LTO)
CXXPICFLAGS = -KPIC
CXX98 = 
CXX98FLAGS =  $(LTO)
CXX98PICFLAGS = 
CXX98STD = 
CXX11 = /opt/csw/gcc4/bin
CXX11FLAGS =  $(LTO)
CXX11PICFLAGS = 
CXX11STD = 
CXX14 = /opt/csw/gcc4/bin
CXX14FLAGS =  $(LTO)
CXX14PICFLAGS = 
CXX14STD = 
CXX17 = 
CXX17FLAGS =  $(LTO)
CXX17PICFLAGS = 
CXX17STD = 
CXX_VISIBILITY = 
DYLIB_EXT = .so
DYLIB_LD = $(CC)
DYLIB_LDFLAGS = -shared -fopenmp# $(CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS)
DYLIB_LINK = $(DYLIB_LD) $(DYLIB_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
ECHO = echo
ECHO_C = \c
ECHO_N = 
ECHO_T = 
F_VISIBILITY = -fvisibility=hidden
## FC is the compiler used for all Fortran as from R 3.6.0
FC = gfortran
FCFLAGS = -g -O2 $(LTO)
## additional libs needed when linking with $(FC), e.g. on some Oracle compilers
FCLIBS_XTRA = 
FFLAGS = -g -O2 $(LTO)
FLIBS =  -lgfortran -lm -R/opt/csw/lib
FPICFLAGS = -fPIC
FOUNDATION_CPPFLAGS = 
FOUNDATION_LIBS = 
JAR = 
JAVA = /usr/bin/java
JAVAC = 
JAVAH = 
## JAVA_HOME might be used in the next three.  
## They are for packages 'JavaGD' and 'rJava'
JAVA_HOME = /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/jre
JAVA_CPPFLAGS = 
JAVA_LIBS = 
JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH = 
LAPACK_LIBS = -L"$(R_HOME)/lib$(R_ARCH)" -lRlapack
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib
## we only need this is if it is external, as otherwise link to R
LIBINTL= 
LIBM = -lm
LIBR0 = 
LIBR1 = 
LIBR =  
LIBS =  -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lnsl -lsocket -lrt -lsunmath -ldl -lm -liconv -licuuc -licui18n
## needed by R CMD config
LIBnn = lib
LIBTOOL = $(SHELL) "$(R_HOME)/bin/libtool"
LTO = 
## needed to build applications linking to static libR
MAIN_LD = $(CC)
MAIN_LDFLAGS = -fopenmp
MAIN_LINK = $(MAIN_LD) $(MAIN_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
MKINSTALLDIRS = "$(R_HOME)/bin/mkinstalldirs"
OBJC = 
OBJCFLAGS =  $(LTO)
OBJC_LIBS = 
OBJCXX = 
R_ARCH = 
RANLIB = ranlib
SAFE_FFLAGS = -g -O2
SED = /usr/xpg4/bin/sed
SHELL = /bin/sh
SHLIB_CFLAGS = 
SHLIB_CXXFLAGS = 
SHLIB_CXXLD = $(CXX)
SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS = -shared
SHLIB_CXX98LD = $(CXX98) $(CXX98STD)
SHLIB_CXX98LDFLAGS = -shared
SHLIB_CXX11LD = $(CXX11) $(CXX11STD)
SHLIB_CXX11LDFLAGS = -shared
SHLIB_CXX14LD = $(CXX14) $(CXX14STD)
SHLIB_CXX14LDFLAGS = -shared
SHLIB_CXX17LD = $(CXX17) $(CXX17STD)
SHLIB_CXX17LDFLAGS = -shared
SHLIB_EXT = .so
SHLIB_FFLAGS = 
SHLIB_LD = $(CC)
SHLIB_LDFLAGS = -shared# $(CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS)
SHLIB_LIBADD = 
## We want to ensure libR is picked up from $(R_HOME)/lib
## before e.g. /usr/local/lib if a version is already installed.
SHLIB_LINK = $(SHLIB_LD) $(SHLIB_LDFLAGS) $(LIBR0) $(LDFLAGS)
SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS = 
SHLIB_OPENMP_FFLAGS = -fopenmp
STRIP_STATIC_LIB = 
STRIP_SHARED_LIB = 
TCLTK_CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include
TCLTK_LIBS = 
YACC = yacc

## Legacy settings:  no longer used by R as of 3.6.0
## Setting FC often sets F77 (on Solaris make even if set)
## so must follow FC in this file.
F77 = gfortran
FCPICFLAGS = -fPIC
F77_VISIBILITY = -fvisibility=hidden
SHLIB_FCLD = $(FC)
SHLIB_FCLDFLAGS = -shared
SHLIB_OPENMP_FCFLAGS = -fopenmp


## for linking to libR.a
STATIC_LIBR = #  "$(R_HOME)/lib$(R_ARCH)/libR.a"  $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)  $(LIBINTL) -lreadline -lncurses  $(LIBS)

## These are recorded as macros for legacy use in packages
## set on AIX, formerly for old glibc (-D__NO_MATH_INLINES)
R_XTRA_CFLAGS = 
##  was formerly set on HP-UX
R_XTRA_CPPFLAGS =  -I"$(R_INCLUDE_DIR)" -DNDEBUG
## currently unset
R_XTRA_CXXFLAGS = 
## used for gfortran in R > 3.6.0
R_XTRA_FFLAGS = 

## SHLIB_CFLAGS SHLIB_CXXFLAGS SHLIB_FFLAGS are apparently currently unused
## SHLIB_CXXFLAGS is undocumented, there is no SHLIB_FCFLAGS
ALL_CFLAGS =  $(PKG_CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
ALL_CPPFLAGS =  -I"$(R_INCLUDE_DIR)" -DNDEBUG $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) $(CLINK_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)
ALL_CXXFLAGS =  $(PKG_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS)
ALL_OBJCFLAGS = $(PKG_OBJCFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CFLAGS) $(OBJCFLAGS)
ALL_OBJCXXFLAGS = $(PKG_OBJCXXFLAGS) $(CXXPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CXXFLAGS) $(OBJCXXFLAGS)
ALL_FFLAGS =  $(PKG_FFLAGS) $(FPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_FFLAGS) $(FFLAGS)
## can be overridden by R CMD SHLIB
P_FCFLAGS = $(PKG_FFLAGS)
ALL_FCFLAGS =  $(P_FCFLAGS) $(FPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_FFLAGS) $(FCFLAGS)
## LIBR here as a couple of packages use this without SHLIB_LINK
ALL_LIBS = $(PKG_LIBS) $(SHLIB_LIBADD) $(LIBR)# $(LIBINTL)

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c .cc .cpp .d .f .f90 .f95 .m .mm .M .o

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.c.d:
    @echo "making $@ from $<"
    @$(CC) -MM $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $< > $@
.m.d:
    @echo > $@
.cc.o:
    $(CXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.cc.d:
    @echo > $@
.cpp.d:
    @echo > $@
.m.o:
    $(OBJC) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.mm.o:
    $(OBJCXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJCXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.M.o:
    $(OBJCXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJCXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.f.o:
    $(FC) $(ALL_FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
## @FCFLAGS_f9x@ are flags needed to recognise the extensions
.f95.o:
    $(FC) $(ALL_FCFLAGS) -c  $< -o $@
.f90.o:
    $(FC) $(ALL_FCFLAGS) -c  $< -o $@
```

Comment: The leading dash in `-I"/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include"` is missing. What is the content of `ALL_CPPFLAGS` defined in `$RHOME/etc/Makeconf`?

Comment: ALL_CPPFLAGS =  -I"$(R_INCLUDE_DIR)" -DNDEBUG $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) $(CLINK_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)

Comment: This looks correct. Can you post the full output from `install.packages(“Rcpp”)`?

Comment: added full output as a image in the question itself

Comment: The previous version with the error message as text was better. You just have to [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: The actual output looks very strange. All these lines should start with the command for the C++ compiler. What is the output of `R CMD config CXX`?

Comment: nothing returned when i ran the command: R CMD config CXX

Comment: So R doe snot know your C++ compiler (I assume you have one installed!). I am pretty sure that R's `configure` script told you about that. Anyway, it *might* work to adjust `CXX`, `CXX11`, `CXX14` in `$RHOME/etc/Makeconf`. It is probably safer to R's `configure` script and see why that did not find the C++ compiler.

Comment: How to configure CXX, CXX11, CXX14 in $RHOME/etc/Makeconf
or is there a way to automate it ?

Comment: These variables are automatically filled via R's `configure` script. Using that would require a re-compilation and -installation, though. Please the the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#C_002b_002b-Support) for manual adjustments (no pun intended ...).

Comment: We have modified all the CXX, CXX11, CXX14 entries, still its getting failed with the error:

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-KPIC'
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `api.o'

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include your `$RHOME/etc/Makeconf`?

Comment: added the Makeconf entries in question itself

Comment: Is this the `Makeconf` before or after changing `CXX` etc? I am asking since the entries as posted are only a path, not the actual executable.

Comment: This is the Makeconf file after changing CXX and etc

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at some parts of the posted `Makeconf` file:

```
CC = gcc -std=gnu99
CFLAGS = -g -O2 $(LTO)
CPICFLAGS = -fPIC
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include
```

This part dealing with C looks fine.

```
CXX = /opt/csw/gcc4/bin
CXXCPP = /lib/cpp
CXXFLAGS =  $(LTO)
CXXPICFLAGS = -KPIC
```

The value of `CXX` must be the executable for the C++ compiler, optionally with full path if it is not in `$PATH`. For example, I have

```
CXX = g++ -std=gnu++11
```

(Note that C++11 is the default nowadays.)

For `CXXFLAGS` you should add optimization. A good starting point could be

```
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 $(LTO)
```

Finally `CXXPICFLAGS` is wrong for your compiler. `-fpic` should work.

Assuming you are using the same compiler for all C++ versions, the `CXXnn*` variables are straightforward:

- `CXXnn` gets the compiler (without any additional flags)
- `CXXnnFLAGS` and `CXXnnPICFLAGS` is the same as `CXXFLAGS` and `CXXPICFLAGS`
- `CXXnnSTD` gets the compiler flags necessary to activate that particular standard, e.g. `CXX98STD = -std=gnu++98` or `CXX11STD = -std=gnu++11`
- Leave all fields empty, if your compiler does not support the standard version, e.g. gcc v4 does not support C++17, and C++14 might be only partial as "C++1y"

Comment: Got the below error:
/opt/csw/gcc4/bin/gcc -I"/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -g -O2  -c api.cpp -o api.o
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `api.o'
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rcpp'
* removing '/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/library/Rcpp'

Comment: @Venkat Do you have a C++ compiler installed? Note that `gcc` is a C compiler, the corresponding C++ compiler being called `g++`.

Comment: Post insalling gcc-c++, we are able to install Rcpp now.

While installing 'stringi', got the below error:

configure: error: in `/tmp/RtmpwWB3Uc/R.INSTALL695b63755d21/stringi':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'stringi'
* removing '/R-3.6.1/R-3.6.1/library/stringi'

Comment: @Venkat It would have been nice if you had told us about the lack of a C++ compiler. Anyway, I can only guess that you modified some parameters in `Makeconf` by accident. Now that you have a C++ compiler installed is probably a good time to re-compile R including the running the `configure` script ...

Comment: Thank you for your continuous help.
I am very new to R and this admin configurations as well.
Could you please provide the steps to re-compile R and guide me on further steps to install RsiteCatalyst package. I came to know that while installing RsiteCatalyst package, these Rcpp, stringi and other 4 packages are dependent to it.

Comment: when i run the install.packages("stringi"); the below error i got
"The ICU4C bundle could not be built. Upgrade your compiler flags"

Comment: @Venkat Now that you have a C++ compiler installed, your previous method for installing R should work fine. From the comments in `Makeconf` it looks like you used tried & tested `configure && make && make install`. For more info please read the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html). Concerning the ICU4C error: From this message alone it is impossible to tell what is going on. Please ask a new question providing all the information needed.